# OAuthException not catched with C# FacebookSDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I try to get my code working with catching certain errors. I store the token for a user after he or she grants permission to my app (this is a WP7 app). When I try to post on the wall by using the stored token it works. When I remove the permissions on facebook it throws an OAuthException. I can't catch it it seems. My app just crashes. This is the code I used:

```
    private object PostToFacebook()
    {
        _fbApp = new FacebookClient(_appsettings.faceBookToken);

        FacebookAsyncCallback callback = new FacebookAsyncCallback(this.postResult);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("message", "message on wall");
        try
        {
            _fbApp.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters, callback);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    private void postResult(FacebookAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        if (asyncResult.Error == null)
        {
            status = "succes";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "error" + asyncResult.Error.Message;
        }
    }
```

The try catch doesn't catch anything and the generic exception handler in my app.xaml.cs either.

Any ideas how to catch this error so I can ask the user to authenticate again?

Answer (score 0):

Put your try..catch in the callback.

You can also catch exceptions globally by handling the `UnhandledException` event on the App object.

Comment: thanks, but the generic UnhandledException never gets fired and the postResult is never called so why should i put a try catch inside that method? Not sure if I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @matthijs If the global unhandled exception isn't picking this up (it won't get everything on background threads) how do you know you're getting an`OAuthException`? Where is it breaking in debug? Put the handling there. The handling should be inside the callback as that is where the result of the call (even an error) will be passed to. Your current try..catch will currently only catch any exceptions thrown when setting up the callback.

Comment: thats the weird thing, when I add the facebook sdk as sourcecode into my project is stops on the throw exception in ln 832 in FacebookClient.cs (nobody catches it). It's pretty easy to reproduce, create a new phone app, add the reference to facebook and add the code above (put some dummy text as token)