# (facebook C# SDK) Any ways to avoid getting an exception thrown when "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the facebook C# SDK, v5.0.3. I develop a silverlight application. 
If my code asks an invalid or unauthorized graph request, for example : http://graph.facebook.com/me/Idonotexists

Facebook returns a "not found" message. Upon that "not found" message, the Facebook C# SDK, in the method FacebookClient:ResponseCallback() throws an exception.

The exception is not catched anywhere and makes the silverlight app to die (IE shows a white empty page).

Is there anyway I can catch the exception? 
  try and catch my request fb.GetAsync(pathBox.Text, parameters, get_data_callback) doesn't work, as it's thrown just before the callback.

The following addition is a functional workaround the issue but it's far from a best practice:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) 
 { 
    e.Handled = true; // do this to prevent white page
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it throws `OAuthException` so all we have to do is catch it.

Well I think this can be caught by Following code .I think It Should work.Tell me does that work?

```
app.GetAsync("me/photo", (friends) =>
            {                    
                    if (friends.Error == null)
                    {
                        dynamic news = friends.Result;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'd guess that the GetAsync method being asynchroneous, the catch sentence is long gone by when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Well what do you want to reterive? pictures ablums what?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what I want to retreive. I am expecting that the SDK is robust enough that if I ask a stupid request, it doesn't make the whole application crash, it just callsme back nicely telling me that there was an error. I can easily comment out the exception thrown in FacebookClient:ResponseCallback(), but I'd much prefer to use the SDK as such.

Comment: well not sure but see the updated reply.leme check my self check after some time updated reply

Comment: Updated the answer Please see.It will not crash and if you want know error just show it in messagebox  or what ever you want.Does that helps

Comment: That doesn't work either. Exactly same behavior than with the previous proposal. The silverlight app crashes or more precisely IE says "error in the page" and doesn't display the application anymore.

Comment: See the functional workaround I have found, embedded in my question. While it works, I don't think it's a reasonable solution. Really the question seems to boil down to why the SDK throws an exception in a asynchroneous method.

Comment: Well i tried in desktop app by giving wrong path It didnot braked.I havent worked on silverlight much .Thanks for tryin

Comment: by the way which Version you are using

Comment: FB C# SDK
‎5.0.4 was built incorrectly they say if you have downloaded switch to 5.0.5.

Comment: I use C# SDK 5.0.3. I will upgrade to 5.0.5 and let you know if the issue is still present.

Comment: I tried it with 5.0.5 it still doesn't work. It's a WP7 app in my case. Debugger breaks at lin 825 in Facebookclient.cs (FacebookOAuthException was unhandled)

Comment: This gives me a clue where you are calling that function you have to place exception there.Can you show code.

Comment: My codesample is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292636/oauthexception-not-catched-with-c-facebooksdk